# Exclude hidden dot files with tar

Tags: gzip, tar

I have a simple `tar` command to copy certain folders and their contents into an archive but I'd like to exclude hidden files such as `.gitkeep` and `.DS_STORE`. I thought I had the correct command (from [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/excluding-hidden-files-folders-in-tarball-644039/)), but the files keep being included anyway.

```
tar -zcvf dist.tar.gz Foo/ Bar/ Buzz/ --exclude=".*"
```

Where `Foo/`, `Bar/` or `Buzz/` contains a hidden file like `.gitkeep`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Order matters with `tar` apparently!

While the command in the question didn't work, rearranging `--exclude` to be at the front did. Many of the guides I found online were either wrong in the example commands they gave or didn't specify, so I thought I would answer my own question when I figured it out.

```
tar --exclude=".*" -zcvf dist.tar.gz Foo/ Bar/ Buzz/
```